# Should I be Using getElementById with the Totals

Tags: javascript-objects

I'm supposed to create a calcExp function (calculate Expenses) but the code I've written isn't qualifying with the online case problem.

Create the calcExp() function. The purpose of this function is to calculate the row and column totals from the travelExp table. Add the following commands to the function:

1. Create the expTable variable referencing all the table row (tr) elements within the table body of the travelExp table.
2. Loop through the rows in the expTable collection and, for each table row, set the value of the input element with the ID subtotalIndex to the value returned by the calcClass() function using the parameter value dateIndex. Where Index is the value of the index counter in the for loop. Format the value returned by the calcClass() function as a text string using the formatNumber() function to 2 decimals.
3. After the for loop, set the values of the transTotal, lodgeTotal, mealTotal, and otherTotal input elements by calling the calcClass() function using parameter values "trans", "lodge", "meal", and "other". Format the values using the formatNumber() to 2 decimal places.
4. Set the value of the expTotal input element to the value returned by the calcClass() function using "sum" as the parameter value. Format the returned value using the formatUSCurrency() function.

`function calcExp() {
  var expTable = document.querySelectorAll("table#travelExp tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < expTable.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("subtotal"+i).value = formatNumber(calcClass(date[i]), 2);
  }
  document.getElementById("transTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass("trans"), 2);
  document.getElementById("lodgeTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass("lodge"), 2);
  document.getElementById("mealTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass("meal"), 2);
  document.getElementById("otherTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass("other"), 2);
  document.getElementById("expTotal").value = formatUSCurrency(calcClass("sum"));
}`

calcClass succeed for me. It is:

```
function calcClass(sumClass) {
  var sumFields = document.querySelectorAll("."+sumClass);
  var sumTotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sumFields.length; i++) {
    var itemValue = parseFloat(sumFields[i].value);
    if (!isNaN(itemValue)) {sumTotal += itemValue;}
  }
  return sumTotal;
}
```

In case you're wondering, formatNumber and formatUSCurrency are functions that come with the exercise. They are:

```
function formatNumber(val, decimals) {
   return val.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: decimals, maximumFractionDigits: decimals});

function formatUSCurrency(val) {
   return val.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: "currency", currency: "USD"} );
```

My error message:

calcExp()
    1) `calcExp()` sets correct subtotal and total values
    2) `calcExp()` sets correct subtotal and total values

0 passing (228ms)
  2 failing

1) calcExp()
       `calcExp()` sets correct subtotal and total values:
     ReferenceError: date is not defined
      at calcExp (dl_expenses.js:51:74)
      at Context. (nt-test-7dd2e611.js:26:5)

2) calcExp()
       `calcExp()` sets correct subtotal and total values:
     ReferenceError: date is not defined
      at calcExp (dl_expenses.js:51:74)
      at Context. (nt-test-7dd2e611.js:48:5)